# Edge morphisms on the Grothendieck spectral sequence in the case that one of the functors is exact

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ be abelian categories and let $G: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}, F: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}$ be left exact functors, with the hypotheses needed to apply the Grothendieck spectral sequence. The edge morphisms of said spectral sequence give us natural maps
$$ R^p F \circ G \to R^p(F \circ G) \quad \text{and} \quad R^q(F \circ G) \to F \circ R^q G.$$

If $F$ is actually exact, one can see directly from the definition using injective resolutions that there is an isomorphism $R^q(F \circ G) \cong F \circ R^q G$, so the first question would be:

1. Is the edge map on the right (of the two above) said isomorphism?

On the other hand, if $G$ is exact I have only managed to construct a natural map $R^p(F \circ G) \to R^p F \circ G$ using injective resolutions. However, here comes the second question:

2. How does this map relate to the edge map on the left (of the two above)? Are they inverses? If not, what can we say about their compositions?

I don't know how to relate both approaches to the maps (edge maps and injective resolutions) so I have no idea how to compare them.

Comment: Maybe EGA III Chapitre 0, 12.1.7 is useful? In the case of sheaf cohomology, it asserts that the natural map $H^p(Y, f_* F) \to H^p(X, F)$ for a map $f\colon X\to Y$ and a sheaf $F$ on $X$ coincides with the edge homomorphism for the Leray spectral sequence.